# BigQuery load - control character as delimiter

Tags: google-bigquery

We have files to load where field values are separated by the "unit separator", `0x1f`
As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.fieldDelimiter), if not printable, it should be encoded in UTF-8.

Using the `bq` CLI, I tried passing the `-F` argument with `U+001F` to no avail though:`BigQuery error in load operation: Field delimiter must be a single character, found:"U+001F"`.
No luck either with `0x1F` or `\x1f, with or without quotes.

Have I the encoding wrong or is it a bug in `bq`, or the API ?

**EDIT**:
Turns out after playing with the explorer that it's the API that doesn't like the delimiter. 
Besides the printable delimiters, you can use `\t` but also the undocumented `\b` (backspace) and `\f` (form field) apparently.
`tab` could be a valid user-entered character in a free-form text field so we need to use a control char *(after conversion from 'unit sep')*

**EDIT2:**:
Note that `\f` as delimiter does work fine through the API directly but not the `bq` CLI (`Field delimiter must be a single character, found:"\f"`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, courtesy of GCP support, this works on Linux:

```
bq load --autodetect --field_delimiter=$(printf '\x1f') [DATASET].[TABLE] gs://[BUCKET]/simple.csv
```

On Windows, it's not that straightforward to return/generate a control character on the command-line. Easier if you use PowerShell.

I agree with `@Felipe`, this is currently a limitation in the `bq CLI` tool, but one that can easily be fixed in the source code in my mind with a `.decode('utf-8')` on the argument in bytes, so that

```
 --field_delimiter=\x1f
```

can work as-is on any platform.

Closing with the hope the `bq CLI team` will consider the enhancement.

Comment: +1. This really saved me hours and hours of analysis. We use a delimiter that is greater than 127 in ascii code, so we had to figure out how to encode it in bq load command. When we used Octal code like ('\0001') we received errors complaining that bq will only treat first character as delimiter, but your post helped us get the data loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, I am tryinng to load CSV file which contains /u0001, I am using below command bq load --autodetect --field_delimiter='/u0001' dataset_name.table_name /home/directory/event_file.csv. But I am getting error BigQuery error in load operation: Field delimiter must be a single character, found:"/u0001".

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `bq load --field_delimiter=$'\x01'`

Answer (score 0):

You found a limitation of the CLI: It won't accept all characters that the API would.

As said in edit2, the solution is to go straight to the API through alternative methods.